# Selenium "page_source" causes TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 300.000

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, timeout, selenium-chromedriver, renderer

I get the following error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\MyPythonStuff\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 754, in page_source
    return self.execute(Command.GET_PAGE_SOURCE)['value']
  File "C:\MyPythonStuff\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 338, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\MyPythonStuff\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 240, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 300.000
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00A05F73+2449267]
    Ordinal0 [0x00938361+1606497]
    Ordinal0 [0x0082F969+522601]
    Ordinal0 [0x008276CF+489167]
    Ordinal0 [0x00826C8C+486540]
    Ordinal0 [0x00826FB5+487349]
    Ordinal0 [0x0082DDD4+515540]
    Ordinal0 [0x00833913+538899]
    Ordinal0 [0x008352CB+545483]
    Ordinal0 [0x008271ED+487917]
    Ordinal0 [0x008337CC+538572]
    Ordinal0 [0x007E31F8+209400]
    Ordinal0 [0x007D9E5B+171611]
    Ordinal0 [0x007C1DD8+73176]
    Ordinal0 [0x007C2E50+77392]
    Ordinal0 [0x007C2DE9+77289]
    Ordinal0 [0x0094D8D7+1693911]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00AA4036+522726]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00AA3D74+522020]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00AB9187+609079]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00AA48A6+524886]
    Ordinal0 [0x00945CBC+1662140]
    Ordinal0 [0x0094F23B+1700411]
    Ordinal0 [0x0094F3A3+1700771]
    Ordinal0 [0x00965215+1790485]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76846359+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77287C24+228]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77287BF4+180]
```

... whenever I run the following

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException, StaleElementReferenceException,\
    NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

chromedriver = r"D:\Program Files\Python\Python38-32\MyPythonStuff\Drivers\chromedriver.exe"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver)

driver.get(url)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value=user_id_input).send_keys(user_id)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value=pass_input).send_keys(password)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value=continue).click()
```

when the next page finishes loading...

```
content = driver.page_source
```

then timeout error pops its ugly face. I have read through several similar looking errors but have not been able to find a fix. Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: interesting addition I noticed... "page_content" works on the same url if i'm not logged in, but once I'm logged in all of the webdriver methods have the same timeout error

Comment: also, the error doesn't appear when I use Edge instead of Chrome.